# Bootstrap apply nav-stacked if small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say we have a simple navigation bar like this:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I add the class "nav-stacked" to it when the window or parent element is smaller than say 940px. Or even better: as soon as the navigation bar can't fit all elements in the same line anymore.

This would be pretty straight forward in javascript, but I'd like to see a pure css/html solution, but without adding @media queries to the bootstrap source code.

Comment: I thought maybe bootstrap provides a special class or something that does this.

Comment: I just found the class "nav-justified" and it does pretty much what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. There is a class called "nav-justified". It simply stacks the navigation pills as soon as they don't fit into a single row anymore.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i guess it stacks pills only after the `768px` breakpoint. And it ignores the width of the pills becouse [Bootstrap uses this code](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css): `media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this CSS to your solution. Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .nav-justified > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```